# How to hide labels until the submit button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

I am working with Spring Controller and JSP project. I have a jsp page in which I have one button which is `Process` and once I click that button, it shows me two radio button just below it and a `Submit` button as well.

And after clicking Submit button, if everything went fine, then I show  - as this data will come from controller -

```
Success= true 
Error= none
```

But as you can see in my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Nmqk/24/). When my form gets loaded after I hit the jsp url it comes like this on the browser -

```
Process

Success= 
Error=
```

Meaning, it has `Process` button at the top and just below `Success` and `Error` label with no values in it as we haven't passed any values yet from the controller. But it looks pretty weird for the users.

So what I am trying to do is, once my page gets loaded or I click Process button - I don't want to show `Success` and `Error` labels at all. It should be shown only after the submit button is clicked with its appropriate value in `Success` and `Error` depending on what is passed from the controller.

Is this possible to do in jquery? If I am right, basically I want to hide it until submit button is clicked...

Or is there any better design to show the Success and Error label with what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you wouldn't need JavaScript to do this since as far as I can tell the form submission goes to the backend.  In JSP itself you could just do a check like:

```
<% if (success.length > 0 || error.length > 0) { %>
    <!-- success / error labels go here -->
<% } %>
```

If you actually wanted to do this via JavaScript, you could use something like:

```
if (!$("#success-value").text().length && !$("#error-value").text().length) {
    // hide the labels
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4Nmqk/25/

Comment: Yeah it works fine with your javascript example.. Thanks a lot Explosion.

Comment: One silly question -  do you see any better design of showing the Success and Error response in my jsfiddle? As currently I am showing as label and they look pretty ugly.. Can you think of something which can match my them and looks slightly better if possible?

Comment: @AKIWEB what do you mean by ugly?  You can style labels with css.

Comment: @ExplosionPills I have the similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23878767/how-to-show-only-the-labels-in-a-div-which-has-some-data-in-it-using-jquery/) as well. Now I am trying to use another label in the same question but not sure how to hide Data label if there is no data in that label. See if you can help me out there.

Answer (score 0):

have a look on my fiddle if it meet your idea.

> jsfiddle.net/4Nmqk/26