# How to show only the labels in a div which has some data in it using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I am working with Spring Controller and JSP project. I have a jsp page in which I have one button which is `Process` and once I click that button, it shows me two radio button just below it and a `Submit` button as well.

And after clicking Submit button, if everything went fine, then I show  like this -

```
Success= true 
Error= none
Data= some_data
```

But as you can see in my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Nmqk/52/). When my form gets loaded after I hit the jsp url it comes like this on the browser -

```
Process

Success= 
Error= 
Data=
```

Meaning, it has `Process` button at the top and just below `Success` , `Error` and `Data` label with no values in it as we haven't passed any values yet from the controller. But it looks pretty weird for the users.

So what I did is once I click Process button - I don't show `Success`, `Error` and `Data` labels at all. It should be shown only after the submit button is clicked with its appropriate value in `Success` , `Error` and `Data` depending on what is passed from the controller.

So this is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Nmqk/50/) which is working for me. Meaning I only see these labels whenever submit button is clicked and it has some data in it

Now what I am trying to do is, if the value of label `Data` is null or empty after pressing the submit button, then I don't want to show `Data` label at all but if the `Success` and `Error` label has some data, then I would show them. How can I do this if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `.hide()` in jquery do not support the hide for `<label>`. So I would suggest to use `<span>` tag for your label instead the `<label>` tag

```
<span id="status">Success= ${SUCCESS}</span>
```

Then in your `javascript`, use `.hide()` and `.show()`, something similar as below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 //hide label
$('#status').hide();
$('#error').hide();
$('#data').hide();

$('.btn-primary').click(function () {
    $('.btn-primary').removeClass('currentButton')
    $(this).addClass('currentButton')
    $('form').hide()
    $("#form_" + $(this).attr('id')).show();
})

$('#submit').click(function(){

    $('#status').show();
    $('#error').show();
    $('#data').show();

});

})
```

[an updated close enough demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyap/4Nmqk/98/)

Comment: I guess this might be another approach but if you see my solution which I have in the jsfiddle. I am using this `if (!$("#success-value").text().length && !$("#error-value").text().length) {
    $("#reporting").hide();   
}` which worked fine to hide the reporting div but if I need to show only data label if it has any data then how to do that using the same set of code if possible.

Comment: in `jsp`, you can direct access the `${SUCCESS}` value. As it was a returned value from your java control.

Comment: In your example, whenever the page gets loaded, it shows `Success= ${SUCCESS}
Error= ${ERRORS}
Error= ${DATA}` and that's what I want to avoid since they don't have any data in them when the page gets loaded. I want to show these labels whenever they have some data in the labels after clicking the submit button.

Comment: Ok. I finally get what you want. Check the updated demo again.

Comment: Ok. That looks good. But I have one more use case which is suppose if any of the labels data is empty, then I don't want to show that label at all. Suppose SUCCESS and ERROR label has data so I will show these two labels but if DATA label doesn't have any data, then I will not show DATA label. This piece is missing I guess.

Comment: Then as I said before, check the `${SUCCESS}` , `${ERRORS}` , `${DATA}` for empty or null and use `.show()` or `.hide()` at your preference. Use a `if` conditional statement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54482/discussion-between-jhyap-and-user2809564).