# How to disable a textbox if particular radio button is clicked using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html form in which I have four radio buttons and one text box. What I am trying to do is - Once I click `Test4` radio button, I want to disable `node` textbox so that nobody can type anything in that. I don't want to hide it, I just want to disable it.

But if anybody clicks either `Test1` or `Test2` or `Test3` then anybody can type anything into it.

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Nmqk/61/)

Is this possible to do using jquery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is possible; I'd suggest:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
    $('#node').prop('disabled', this.value === 'test4');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4Nmqk/62/).

This sets the `disabled` property of the `#node` element to `true` (if the changed-element has the value of 'test4'), and to `false` if it does not.

Further to the discussion in comments (wherein, basically, the OP revealed that checking other `input` elements of `type="radio"` caused the `#node` element to become re-enabled), I've amended the HTML to offer a simple means of associating the appropriate `input`s with the specific text-input, using `data-affects`. giving the following HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="data" id="test1" value="test1" data-affects="nodes" />Test1 
<input type="radio" name="data" id="test2" value="test2" data-affects="nodes" />Test2 
<input type="radio" name="data" id="test3" value="test3" data-affects="nodes" />Test3 
<input type="radio" name="data" id="test4" value="test4" data-affects="nodes" />Test4
```

Coupled with the amended jQuery:

```
$('input[type="radio"][data-affects]').change(function(){
    $('#' + this.getAttribute('data-affects')).prop('disabled', this.value === 'test4');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4Nmqk/83/).

References:

- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. It worked fine, if I have only one button at the top which is  `Process` button. But if I have two buttons, let's say `Process` and `Testing`. And they both have separate forms for them and then it  doesn't work if I click on `test4` radio button. Here is the [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4Nmqk/65/). Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Duplicate `id`s. They are invalid, and cause problems; an `id` ***must be unique within the document***. I'd recommend creating some form of grouping to associate the input elements with the relevant/specific `input` you want to affect.

Comment: Thanks for giving me nice tip. I have added unique id for each element now. But in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Nmqk/74/) - I am seeing pretty weird  problem. As soon as I click `Test4` radio button, it disables the node textbox but if I click any of the radio buttons just below it, either `TestClient` or `TestServer`, then `node` textbox gets enabled automatically. Not sure what's wrong. Any idea?

Comment: Because the selector is bound to *all* `input[type="radio"]` elements, and has nothing more unique than the value to identify which one matters. Could you maybe give some clear direction as to which radio-inputs should affect which text-input?

Comment: Sure. I want to disable `node` textbox only whenever I am clicking `Test4` radio button. But If I am clicking either `Test1` or `Test2` or `Test3` then node textbox should be enabled and anybody can type anything into it.

Comment: Right, so those four should deal with `#node`, the other two should deal with whatever the other one is?

Comment: Top four radio button is for `nodes` textbox and the bottom two radio button is for some other purpose and those should not conflict with the above four radio buttons click.

Comment: Yup worked fine now. Thanks for the help. I also have one more question on jquery and html [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23878767/how-to-show-only-the-labels-in-a-div-which-has-some-data-in-it-using-jquery) See if you can help me out there as well if possible. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

To your jsfiddle, add on the top of js this piece of code:

```
$("input:radio[name=data]").change(function () {
    var checkedValue = $(this).val();
    if (checkedValue == "test4") {
        $("#node").prop("disabled", true);
    } else {
        $("#node").prop("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

You can also call the radio group by id instead of name:

```
$("input:radio[id=data]").change(function () { //first line of code
```

Live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/pw9nZ/

Hope this helps you...

Theo.